# type error: 0 positional argument but 2 were giving (I can't find where is my bug)

Tags: python

```
 def is_leap(year):
  if year % 4 == 0:
    if year % 100 == 0:
      if year % 400 == 0:
        return True
      else:
        return False
    else:
      return True
  else:
    return False

def days_in_month():
    month_days = [31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31]  
    if month == 2 and is_leap(year) == True:
        return month_days[2] == 29
    return month_days[month-1]

year = int(input("Enter a year: "))
month = int(input("Enter a month: "))
days = days_in_month(year, month)
print(days)
```

I was written code to tell how many day in that month and year, after I wrote and run it, they tell me my argument is 0 where given is 2, I don't know why it have error by my understanding the function day_in_month already have 2 argument from year and month.

Comment: Your days_in_month function doesn't take any parameters but you pass it the variables year and month

Comment: No, the function `days_in_month` is defined with 0 arguments - `def days_in_month()` yet you call it with two arguments - `year` and `month`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code doesn't work because when you defined the function you didn't include the arguments, this should fix the problem:

```
def days_in_month(year, month):
    month_days = [31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31]  
    if month == 2 and is_leap(year) == True:
        return month_days[2] == 29
    return month_days[month-1]
```

Please refer to the [wiki](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_functions.asp) if you have any doubts